# Stored Procedure Insert Error: Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is the only error I get. Please Help. Thank you in advance.

After I successfully created and a stored procedure in SQL Server. I tried to execute it with the following (example only)

```
exec [dbo].ExportResourceTime 'ABC111', '', 3, 1, '2013-10-01', '2013-10-30', 1, 21
```

Then I get the following error. See attached photo.

This is the actual error in SSMS. Line 96 is the gray cursor on top of if @OrgUnit <> ''

[image]

This is the independent script which I think the error comes from. Correct me if I'm wrong.

[image]

> Msg 213, Level 16, State 1, Procedure ExportResourceTime, Line 96
>   Insert Error: Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

Code:

```
create procedure [dbo].ExportResourceTime
        @ResourceID nvarchar(30),
            @OrgUnit nvarchar(15),
            @TimeDetail int,
            @ExpenseDetail int,
            @FromDate Datetime,
            @ToDate Datetime,
            @IncludeID int,
            @TimeTypeGroup int
            --1 = No Time Type Group
            --2 = Group by Time Type
as
BEGIN 
   create table #ItemisedTimeandMaterials
   (
      IDNo int,
      OrderBy1 varchar(60),
      ItemDate datetime,--MOD005
      RevenueTypeCode varchar(24),
      TimeType varchar(24),
      ProjectCode varchar(20),
      taskUID int,
      OutlineNum varchar(60),
      taskname varchar(60),
      activitycode varchar(24),
      ActivityDesc varchar(60),
      ResourceID nvarchar(24),
      OrganizationID nvarchar(15),
      EffectiveDate datetime,
      firstname varchar(60),
      lastname varchar(60),
      ExpenseTypeCode varchar(24),
      ExpenseTypeDesc varchar(60),
      Hours decimal(8,2),
      Rate decimal(8,2),
      Total decimal(20,8),
      Descr varchar(256), --MOD005 DM Added col for relevant detail for Expenses
      TimeTypeCode nvarchar(10)
     )
--GW: move this bit to the top--DONE

create table #Resources
(
ResourceID nvarchar(30),
OrganizationID nvarchar(15),
EffectiveDate datetime
)


if @ResourceID <> ''
 begin
 insert into #Resources (ResourceID,OrganizationID,EffectiveDate)

    select ro.ResourceID, ro.OrganizationID, ro.EffectiveDate from ResourceOrganization ro,
    (select ResourceID, MAX(EffectiveDate) as maxEffectivedate from dbo.ResourceOrganization
    **where ResourceID = @ResourceID**
    group by ResourceID) as maxresults
    where ro.ResourceID = maxresults.ResourceID
    and ro.EffectiveDate = maxresults.maxEffectivedate
    end

if @OrgUnit <> ''
 begin
 insert into #Resources (ResourceID,OrganizationID,EffectiveDate)
  Select  ResourceID,OrganizationID,EffectiveDate from ResourceOrganization
  where OrganizationID like '' + @OrgUnit + '%'
   end

-- get actual time - REGULAR
insert into #ItemisedTimeandMaterials
select      
Case when @IncludeID = 1 then b.timeID else '' end, --mod 07
e.lastname + e.firstname, 
case when @TimeDetail = 2 then g.enddate else (case when @TimeDetail = 3 then b.TimeEntryDate else null end) end,--MOD005
'FEES',
'Regular',
b.projectcode,
b.taskuid,
f.outlinenum,
f.taskname,
b.ActivityCode,
c.ActivityDesc,
b.resourceID,
RES.OrganizationID,
e.firstname,
e.lastname,
'','', -- expense
sum(isnull(b.StandardHours,0)), -- MOD003 - added in isnull's
0,--h.StandardAmt,--b.NegotiatedChargeRate, --MOD005 Change to NegotiatedChargeRate from StandardChargeRate
0,--sum(isnull(b.StandardHours,0)* IsNull(h.standardAmt,0)),--sum(bd.BilledAmt),--MOD005 Change from BillableAmt feild (was incorrect for adjustments)
case when @TimeDetail = 3 then b.invoicecomment else '' end,--MOD005
case when @TimeTypeGroup = 2 then b.TimeTypeCode else '' end--MOD008

from time b 
join activity c
on b.activitycode = c.activitycode
join resource e 
on b.resourceID = e.resourceID
join project p 
on b.ProjectCode=p.ProjectCode 
and p.RevisionStatusCode='A'
join task f 
on b.projectcode = f.projectcode 
and b.taskuid =f.taskuid 
and f.revisionnum = p.RevisionNum
join SCWeekEnding g   
on b.TimeEntryDate between g.StartDate and g.EndDate
join #Resources RES
on b.ResourceID = RES.ResourceID
--left join ratesetresource h on h.resourceid = b.resourceid
where       --b.projectcode = @PROJECTCODE and
b.statuscode in ('A','V','T')
and b.TimeEntryDate >= @FromDate
and b.TimeEntryDate <= @ToDate
and Isnull(b.StandardHours,0) <> 0
and b.resourceid in(Select ResourceId from #Resources)


group by  
b.projectcode,
b.taskuid,
f.outlinenum,
f.taskname,
b.ActivityCode,
c.ActivityDesc,
b.resourceID,
RES.OrganizationID,
e.firstname,
e.lastname,

case when @TimeDetail = 2 then g.enddate else (case when @TimeDetail = 3 then b.TimeEntryDate else null end) end,--MOD005
case when @TimeDetail = 3 then b.invoicecomment else '' end,
Case when @IncludeID = 1 then b.timeID else '' end, --mod 07
case when @TimeTypeGroup = 2 then b.TimeTypeCode else '' end--MOD008
having sum(isnull(b.StandardHours,0)) <> 0 


-- get actual time - OVERTIME
insert into #ItemisedTimeandMaterials
select      
Case when @IncludeID = 1 then b.timeID else '' end, --mod 07
e.lastname + e.firstname, 
case when @TimeDetail = 2 then g.enddate else (case when @TimeDetail = 3 then b.TimeEntryDate else null end) end,--MOD005
'FEES',
'Overtime',
--GW: need projectcode here--DONE
b.projectcode,
b.taskuid,
f.outlinenum,
f.taskname,
b.ActivityCode,
c.ActivityDesc,
b.resourceID,
RES.OrganizationID as OrgUnit,
e.firstname,
e.lastname,
'','', -- expense
sum(isnull(b.OvertimeHours,0)), -- MOD003 - added in isnull's
0,
0,
case when @TimeDetail = 3 then b.invoicecomment else '' end, --MOD005
case when @TimeTypeGroup = 2 then b.TimeTypeCode else '' end--MOD008
from time b 
join activity c 
on b.activitycode = c.activitycode
join resource e 
on b.resourceID = e.resourceID
join project p 
on b.ProjectCode=p.ProjectCode 
and p.RevisionStatusCode='A'
join task f
on b.projectcode = f.projectcode 
and b.taskuid =f.taskuid 
and f.revisionnum = p.RevisionNum
join SCWeekEnding g   
on b.TimeEntryDate between g.StartDate and g.EndDate
join #Resources RES
on b.ResourceID = RES.ResourceID

where       
b.statuscode in ('A','V','T')
--and f.revisionnum = @latestapprovedrevision
and b.TimeEntryDate >= @FromDate
and b.TimeEntryDate <= @ToDate
and Isnull(b.OvertimeHours,0) <> 0
and b.resourceid in (select resourceid from #Resources)

group by  
--GW: projectcode here--DONE
b.projectcode,
b.taskuid,
f.outlinenum,
f.taskname,
b.ActivityCode,
c.ActivityDesc,
b.resourceID,
RES.OrganizationID,
e.firstname,
e.lastname,

case when @TimeDetail = 2 then g.enddate else (case when @TimeDetail = 3 then b.TimeEntryDate else null end) end,--MOD005
case when @TimeDetail = 3 then b.invoicecomment else '' end,
case when @IncludeID = 1 then b.TimeID else '' end ,--mod 07
case when @TimeTypeGroup = 2 then b.TimeTypeCode else '' end--MOD008
having sum(isnull(b.Overtimehours,0)) <> 0

/**************** SECTION 7: OUTPUT DATA TO CRYSTAL REPORT ******************/

-- return data to the Crystal report only if taskuid are in table 1

select * 
from #ItemisedTimeandMaterials
order by taskUID

drop table #Resources
drop table #ItemisedTimeandMaterials

END

GO
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 23 columns in your `#ItemisedTimeandMaterials` temporary table while you are inserting only 22 values from select list.

When inserting into table with large number of columns with computed values from SELECT list, you can keep track of columns by giving alias name to each computed column same as the target temporary table column.

In this way you can easily compare the table columns and the columns in select list and find out missing column.

The missing column is EffectiveDate , add it to select list at correct position

```
Select
..
..
b.resourceID,
RES.OrganizationID,
RES.EffectiveDate, --- Missing column
e.firstname,
e.lastname, 
...
..
```

Comment: It works perfectly fine before, I just added EffectiveDate from the Create Table #Resources. So I added the EffectiveDate Resources in the #ItemisedTimeandMaterials temp table. So I presume the columns and values are balanced.

Comment: EffectiveDate is missing from Select list while inserting in `#ItemisedTimeandMaterials` table

Comment: Thank you Mhasan for helping me with this! Im the only Junior BI dev in our company and honeslty... I badly need help. Thanks to all of you!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if @ResourceID <> ''
    begin
        insert into #Resources (ResourceID,OrganizationID,EffectiveDate)

            Select ro.ResourceID,
                   ro.OrganizationID,
                   ro.EffectiveDate
            from ResourceOrganization ro
            inner join (select ResourceID,
                               MAX(EffectiveDate) as maxEffectivedate
                        from dbo.ResourceOrganization
                        where ResourceID = @ResourceID
                        group by ResourceID) as maxresults on ro.ResourceID = maxresults.ResourceID
                                                          and ro.EffectiveDate = maxresults.maxEffectivedate
    end
```

EDIT:
try executing it like this line

```
EXEC dbo.ExportResourceTime @ResourceID = N'ABC111', @OrgUnit = N'', @TimeDetail = 3, @ExpenseDetail = 1, @FromDate = '2013-10-01 00:00:00', @ToDate = '2013-10-30 00:00:00', @IncludeID = 1, @TimeTypeGroup = 21
```

I dont have your Database, so its hard to spot the fault from the other side of the world.

I have somewhat formatted your Script, But cant see anything wrong, I can't run the script aswell because of my above mentioned problem

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].ExportResourceTime
    @ResourceID NVARCHAR(30),
    @OrgUnit NVARCHAR(15),
    @TimeDetail INT,
    @ExpenseDetail INT,
    @FromDate DATETIME,
    @ToDate DATETIME,
    @IncludeID INT,
    @TimeTypeGroup INT
            --1 = No Time Type Group
            --2 = Group by Time Type
AS 
    BEGIN 
        CREATE TABLE #ItemisedTimeandMaterials
            (
             IDNo INT,
             OrderBy1 VARCHAR(60),
             ItemDate DATETIME,--MOD005
             RevenueTypeCode VARCHAR(24),
             TimeType VARCHAR(24),
             ProjectCode VARCHAR(20),
             taskUID INT,
             OutlineNum VARCHAR(60),
             taskname VARCHAR(60),
             activitycode VARCHAR(24),
             ActivityDesc VARCHAR(60),
             ResourceID NVARCHAR(24),
             OrganizationID NVARCHAR(15),
             EffectiveDate DATETIME,
             firstname VARCHAR(60),
             lastname VARCHAR(60),
             ExpenseTypeCode VARCHAR(24),
             ExpenseTypeDesc VARCHAR(60),
             Hours DECIMAL(8, 2),
             Rate DECIMAL(8, 2),
             Total DECIMAL(20, 8),
             Descr VARCHAR(256), --MOD005 DM Added col for relevant detail for Expenses
             TimeTypeCode NVARCHAR(10)
            )
--GW: move this bit to the top--DONE

        CREATE TABLE #Resources
            (
             ResourceID NVARCHAR(30),
             OrganizationID NVARCHAR(15),
             EffectiveDate DATETIME
            )


        IF @ResourceID <> '' 
            BEGIN
                INSERT  INTO #Resources
                        (ResourceID,
                         OrganizationID,
                         EffectiveDate)
                        SELECT  ro.ResourceID,
                                ro.OrganizationID,
                                ro.EffectiveDate
                        FROM    ResourceOrganization ro,
                                (SELECT ResourceID,
                                        MAX(EffectiveDate) AS maxEffectivedate
                                 FROM   dbo.ResourceOrganization
                                 WHERE  ResourceID = @ResourceID
                                 GROUP BY ResourceID) AS maxresults
                        WHERE   ro.ResourceID = maxresults.ResourceID
                                AND ro.EffectiveDate = maxresults.maxEffectivedate
            END

        IF @OrgUnit <> '' 
            BEGIN
                INSERT  INTO #Resources
                        (ResourceID,
                         OrganizationID,
                         EffectiveDate)
                        SELECT  ResourceID,
                                OrganizationID,
                                EffectiveDate
                        FROM    ResourceOrganization
                        WHERE   OrganizationID LIKE '' + @OrgUnit + '%'
            END

-- get actual time - REGULAR
        INSERT  INTO #ItemisedTimeandMaterials
                SELECT  CASE WHEN @IncludeID = 1 THEN b.timeID
                             ELSE ''
                        END, --mod 07
                        e.lastname + e.firstname,
                        CASE WHEN @TimeDetail = 2 THEN g.enddate
                             ELSE (CASE WHEN @TimeDetail = 3 THEN b.TimeEntryDate
                                        ELSE NULL
                                   END)
                        END,--MOD005
                        'FEES',
                        'Regular',
                        b.projectcode,
                        b.taskuid,
                        f.outlinenum,
                        f.taskname,
                        b.ActivityCode,
                        c.ActivityDesc,
                        b.resourceID,
                        RES.OrganizationID,
                        e.firstname,
                        e.lastname,
                        '',
                        '', -- expense
                        SUM(ISNULL(b.StandardHours, 0)), -- MOD003 - added in isnull's
                        0,--h.StandardAmt,--b.NegotiatedChargeRate, --MOD005 Change to NegotiatedChargeRate from StandardChargeRate
                        0,--sum(isnull(b.StandardHours,0)* IsNull(h.standardAmt,0)),--sum(bd.BilledAmt),--MOD005 Change from BillableAmt feild (was incorrect for adjustments)
                        CASE WHEN @TimeDetail = 3 THEN b.invoicecomment
                             ELSE ''
                        END,--MOD005
                        CASE WHEN @TimeTypeGroup = 2 THEN b.TimeTypeCode
                             ELSE ''
                        END--MOD008
                FROM    time b
                JOIN    activity c ON b.activitycode = c.activitycode
                JOIN    resource e ON b.resourceID = e.resourceID
                JOIN    project p ON b.ProjectCode = p.ProjectCode
                                     AND p.RevisionStatusCode = 'A'
                JOIN    task f ON b.projectcode = f.projectcode
                                  AND b.taskuid = f.taskuid
                                  AND f.revisionnum = p.RevisionNum
                JOIN    SCWeekEnding g ON b.TimeEntryDate BETWEEN g.StartDate AND g.EndDate
                JOIN    #Resources RES ON b.ResourceID = RES.ResourceID
--left join ratesetresource h on h.resourceid = b.resourceid
                WHERE   --b.projectcode = @PROJECTCODE and
                        b.statuscode IN ('A', 'V', 'T')
                        AND b.TimeEntryDate >= @FromDate
                        AND b.TimeEntryDate <= @ToDate
                        AND ISNULL(b.StandardHours, 0) <> 0
                        AND b.resourceid IN (SELECT ResourceId
                                             FROM   #Resources)
                GROUP BY b.projectcode,
                        b.taskuid,
                        f.outlinenum,
                        f.taskname,
                        b.ActivityCode,
                        c.ActivityDesc,
                        b.resourceID,
                        RES.OrganizationID,
                        e.firstname,
                        e.lastname,
                        CASE WHEN @TimeDetail = 2 THEN g.enddate
                             ELSE (CASE WHEN @TimeDetail = 3 THEN b.TimeEntryDate
                                        ELSE NULL
                                   END)
                        END,--MOD005
                        CASE WHEN @TimeDetail = 3 THEN b.invoicecomment
                             ELSE ''
                        END,
                        CASE WHEN @IncludeID = 1 THEN b.timeID
                             ELSE ''
                        END, --mod 07
                        CASE WHEN @TimeTypeGroup = 2 THEN b.TimeTypeCode
                             ELSE ''
                        END--MOD008
                HAVING  SUM(ISNULL(b.StandardHours, 0)) <> 0 


-- get actual time - OVERTIME
        INSERT  INTO #ItemisedTimeandMaterials
                SELECT  CASE WHEN @IncludeID = 1 THEN b.timeID
                             ELSE ''
                        END, --mod 07
                        e.lastname + e.firstname,
                        CASE WHEN @TimeDetail = 2 THEN g.enddate
                             ELSE (CASE WHEN @TimeDetail = 3 THEN b.TimeEntryDate
                                        ELSE NULL
                                   END)
                        END,--MOD005
                        'FEES',
                        'Overtime',
--GW: need projectcode here--DONE
                        b.projectcode,
                        b.taskuid,
                        f.outlinenum,
                        f.taskname,
                        b.ActivityCode,
                        c.ActivityDesc,
                        b.resourceID,
                        RES.OrganizationID AS OrgUnit,
                        e.firstname,
                        e.lastname,
                        '',
                        '', -- expense
                        SUM(ISNULL(b.OvertimeHours, 0)), -- MOD003 - added in isnull's
                        0,
                        0,
                        CASE WHEN @TimeDetail = 3 THEN b.invoicecomment
                             ELSE ''
                        END, --MOD005
                        CASE WHEN @TimeTypeGroup = 2 THEN b.TimeTypeCode
                             ELSE ''
                        END--MOD008
                FROM    time b
                JOIN    activity c ON b.activitycode = c.activitycode
                JOIN    resource e ON b.resourceID = e.resourceID
                JOIN    project p ON b.ProjectCode = p.ProjectCode
                                     AND p.RevisionStatusCode = 'A'
                JOIN    task f ON b.projectcode = f.projectcode
                                  AND b.taskuid = f.taskuid
                                  AND f.revisionnum = p.RevisionNum
                JOIN    SCWeekEnding g ON b.TimeEntryDate BETWEEN g.StartDate AND g.EndDate
                JOIN    #Resources RES ON b.ResourceID = RES.ResourceID
                WHERE   b.statuscode IN ('A', 'V', 'T')
--and f.revisionnum = @latestapprovedrevision
                        AND b.TimeEntryDate >= @FromDate
                        AND b.TimeEntryDate <= @ToDate
                        AND ISNULL(b.OvertimeHours, 0) <> 0
                        AND b.resourceid IN (SELECT resourceid
                                             FROM   #Resources)
                GROUP BY  
--GW: projectcode here--DONE
                        b.projectcode,
                        b.taskuid,
                        f.outlinenum,
                        f.taskname,
                        b.ActivityCode,
                        c.ActivityDesc,
                        b.resourceID,
                        RES.OrganizationID,
                        e.firstname,
                        e.lastname,
                        CASE WHEN @TimeDetail = 2 THEN g.enddate
                             ELSE (CASE WHEN @TimeDetail = 3 THEN b.TimeEntryDate
                                        ELSE NULL
                                   END)
                        END,--MOD005
                        CASE WHEN @TimeDetail = 3 THEN b.invoicecomment
                             ELSE ''
                        END,
                        CASE WHEN @IncludeID = 1 THEN b.TimeID
                             ELSE ''
                        END,--mod 07
                        CASE WHEN @TimeTypeGroup = 2 THEN b.TimeTypeCode
                             ELSE ''
                        END--MOD008
                HAVING  SUM(ISNULL(b.Overtimehours, 0)) <> 0

/**************** SECTION 7: OUTPUT DATA TO CRYSTAL REPORT ******************/

-- return data to the Crystal report only if taskuid are in table 1

        SELECT  *
        FROM    #ItemisedTimeandMaterials
        ORDER BY taskUID

        DROP TABLE #Resources
        DROP TABLE #ItemisedTimeandMaterials

    END

GO
```

Comment: @BA82283 look at the edit, but what does it say.. what is the error you get when trying it my first way?

Comment: It says that theres an error in the highlighted 
-- get actual time - REGULAR
        INSERT  INTO #ItemisedTimeandMaterials    
Msg 213, Level 16, State 1, Procedure ExportResourceTime, Line 86
Insert Error: Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

Comment: Pierre, I was missing RES.EffectiveDate, under the -- get actual time - OVERTIME temp table. Thank you for helping me with this. I appreciate the time and effort. Let me know how I can vote for you or anything I could do for you in return.

Comment: Im glad you are sorted. No voting is needed since I didn't help you to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

check table and query (datatype and value Supplied Length) are Same and not

Comment: The stored procedure works fine before, but when I added the EffectiveDate datetime and Max(effectiveDate) that started the errors I get. From the Main Table ResourceOrganization, the EffectiveDate column's data type is datetime. Is there any other data type I could use that would accept the records when doing the insert?